# Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n + a} - \sqrt{n}), a > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n + a} - \sqrt{n}), a > 0$

Would it be right to start by rewriting it as $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/2}((n+a)^{1/2} - n^{1/2})$?

Comment: It would be right, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint:

$$\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt n=\frac a{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt n}$$

Comment: OH yeah. Totally forgot I could do that. Then I have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}*a}{\sqrt{n + a} + \sqrt{n}}$ then... am I on the right track if I did this? $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{\frac{\sqrt{n + a}}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Comment: Correct @Brian, and now yu can take the denominator square into the numerator's (after all everybody's positive here) to see even more clearly what's going on...Of course, it should be $$\frac a{\frac{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt n}}$$